# Spring Maven: Correct the classpath of you application

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am getting the following error when trying to run my spring project:

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1236)

The following method did not exist:

    'javax.persistence.Index[] javax.persistence.Table.indexes()'

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/bobal/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.14.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.14.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/EntityBinder.class

The called method's class, javax.persistence.Table, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/bobal/Documents/Java%20Projects/restService/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/bobal/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/bobal/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.persistence.Table: file:/C:/Users/bobal/Documents/Java%20Projects/restService/lib/javax.persistence.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder and javax.persistence.Table


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think that this error may be due to having conflicting versions of some dependencies, but I'm not very sure. This is my first ever Spring project.

Here is my UPDATED pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>restService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jdbc.version>8.2.2.jre11</jdbc.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.14.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If you find anything wrong please feel free to point it out and explain why. Trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: You should not define a version for hibernate nor for spring-data-jpa which is handled by the spring boot parent.

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you, I have edited to pom.xml file and removed those.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple version of JPA libraries, that's why you are getting this error.

```
jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar and  
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
```

You can remove `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` dependency because it is also present in `jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I can't find that I'm using "jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar" anywhere. Could you point out where this is? I updated the pom file to show what I've changed.

Comment: Could you delete your m2 repository and try a fresh clean build? In case jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar is already existing in your m2 repo, it may work.

Comment: I will try that after you explain why you think I'm using jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar. I have never heard of this nor is there any reference to it that I can find in my project.

Comment: @ColePerry you probably have it as a transitive dependency (included via another dependency). You can use `mvn dependency:tree`  to check where it's included.

Comment: Ok yes I do see this now. I am deleting the m2 folder and doing a clean build now.

Comment: Ok m2 repo deleted and clean build done. Same error.